# How to create objects of certain class by taking input from user

Tags: c++, object

I had this assignment to write and read the objects from file .But what I am not able to get is how to creates objects of a certain class by user input.I am still learning CPP. Here is my code
I have a idea but dont know if it will work .Create object like Bus b1(var1,var2,var3,var4).Will it Work?

```
class Bus
{
    private:
        int busno;
        string to;
        string from;
        float time;
    public:
        Bus()
        {
            busno=0;
            to="";
            from"";
            time=0.0;
        }
        Bus(int busno,string to,string from,float time)
        {
            this->busno=busno;
            this->to-to;
            this->from=from;
            this->time=time;
        }
        void Write()
        {

            fstream file;

            file.open("output.txt");
            file.fseekp(0,ios::end);
            file.write((char*)this,sizeof(Bus));
            file.close();

        }
        void Read()
        {
            fstream file;
            file.open("output.txt");
            file.fseekg(0,ios::beg);
            while(file.read((char*)this,sizeof(Bus)));
            {
                cout<<"The bus no is "<<busno;
                cout<<"The bus will run from "<<from;
                cout<<"The bus will run till "<<to;
                cout<<"The bus will run at time "<<time;

            }
            file.close();
        }

}; 
int main()
{
int ch;
int busno;
string to,from;
float time;
    while(1)
    {


        switch(ch)
        {
          case 1:
                 Bus b1(1234,x,y,19.30);
                 Bus.Write();
                 break;
          case 2:
                 Bus.Read();
                 break;
        }
    } 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't just read & write an object. Should serialize it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this compile? It doesn't look like it.

Where are you expecting 'ch' to get a value?

You can't instantiate within case statements - you need to enclose the case statement contents between curly braces, at least.

Member function calls should look like 'b1.Write();'.

Lastly, whilst writing binary data and reading it back should work, it will be non-portable and fragile. It may not work between different compilers, and almost certainly won't work between big- and small-endian systtems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .It solved my problem .I had skipped the input output part of switch case  while posting the answer.